# When input has :focus, dont trigger :hover styles

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I got a input which I styled with a `:focus` and `:hover`.
When the input has `:focus`, I don't want to have the `:hover` style triggered when I hover over the input.

How am I supposed to style that?

My css is as follow:

```
.form-control:hover {
   border-color: #a9a9a9;
}

.form-control:focus {
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 2px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 2px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

Answer (score 48):

There's an specific CSS selector for this, the `:not` selector. And it has [good compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#Browser_compatibility):

```css
a:hover:not(:focus) {
  color: magenta;
}

a:focus:not(:hover) {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

I also suggest you give preference to the `focus` event, since it's somewhat more *"static"* than the hover state, with something like this:

```css
a:hover:not(:focus) {
  color: magenta;
}

a:focus {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

And for a backwards-compatible alternative:

```css
a:hover {
  color: magenta;
}

a:focus {
  color: cyan;
}

a:focus:hover {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

In simple words:

You have a rule for each state (*magenta* for `hover` and *cyan* for `focus`) and one for both, giving preference (visually) to the `focus` state: *cyan*.

Comment: The "backwards-compatible alternative" worked fantastically, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a `:not(:focus)` to your `:hover` rule like so:

```
.form-control:hover:not(:focus) {
   border-color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

If browser support is an issue (as `:not()` is not supported in IE8 and lower), you will probably just have to write a new rule combining `:hover` and `:focus` to override the `:hover` rule with a hard-coded color value (as the initial value of `border-color`, `currentColor`, is not supported in IE8 and lower either):

```
.form-control:hover {
   border-color: #a9a9a9;
}

.form-control:hover:focus {
   border-color: /* Default border color depending on your layout */;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative, backwards-compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

quick hack: add a border: solid 0px #FFFFFF to .form-control:focus

Comment: You probably meant border-width.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the border on focus works:

```
.form-control:hover {
    border-color: #a9a9a9;
}
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 2px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 2px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    border: none;
}
```

Or set the border to transparent on focus to not have the form 'jump'.

```
.form-control:hover {
    border-color: #a9a9a9;
}
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 2px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 2px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

See here: http://codepen.io/TheNathanG/pen/eCtiu

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `pointer-events: none` declaration when input has `:focus`: http://jsfiddle.net/kbLP9/.

```
.form-control:focus {
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 2px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 2px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Another solution is to combine pseudo-classes `:focus` and `:hover` to achieve the desired effect: http://jsfiddle.net/7LbNV/.

```
.form-control:focus:hover {
    border-color: initial;
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `pointer-events` solely to prevent hover effects on form fields and other elements where the user expects to be able to interact with them using the mouse in other ways than just hover. `border-color: initial` can be replaced with `border-color: currentColor` for a little more browser compatibility.